# How to convert pointer value obtained via reference operator to string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, type-conversion

I am a beginner in C++. I am working on this project where it is required to trace the memory address. Unfortunately, this tracing function has following prototype declaration:

```
void TRC(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, uint64_t, const char*)
```

Now the options available for me are:

1. Convert this memory address (pointer value) to `uint64_t` type. But I've read somewhere that it is not recommended, as pointer value returned by reference operator is platform dependent and conversion of a pointer to an integer may return wrong value.
2. Convert this memory address to string and pass it via last parameter. In Python it was easy as we had `str()` function. Do we have something similar in C++ too?

Please let me know if I am inferring something wrong in my approach/understanding here.

Comment: Memory addresses are not 'in hexadecimal'. They are just numbers, and are converted to hexadecimal (maybe) when you print them out. If you want to print the numeric value of your address then you have no choice but to convert it to an integer at some point. Of course the value will be platform dependent, all memory addresses are. I would go for option 1.

Comment: I think you are confusing how numbers are presented and how they are stored in the computer. All numbers are stored in _binary_ on the computer, but can be presented in a number of representations, including decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: Joachim, I was referring to pointer value obtained by reference operator. I will edit the title of this question. John, how will you convert this hexadecimal value to uint64_t?

Comment: @previous commenters: Numbers are neither hexadecimal nor binary, and you don't "convert a number to hexadecimal", either. Only *representations* of a number can be binary, hexadecimal, roman numerals, etc.

Comment: Furthering that, addresses themselves are implementation-defined (or so I remember with somewhat surprise when reading the standard).  you could always use a standard-approved mechanic like `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (if provided by your implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use streams to convert if it does not need to be fast code.

```
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iomanip>

...
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::hex << static_cast<void*>(my_pointer);
    TRC(..., os.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that a pointer should not be stored or passed as any integer types.

If you want to convert a pointer to a printable hexadecimal string, you can use e.g. [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream os;

os << std::hex << static_cast<void*>(some_pointer);

std::string str = os.str();
TRC(...,  str.c_str());
```

Comment: Most STL implementations don't have an implicit cast from std::string to const char*.

Comment: Why `reinterpret_cast`? Why not `static_cast`?